# ROs-Pcl question

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its a very basic question but i tried to read everything n now m confused.
"i am totally new at ros and pcl though".
we are working with a project robot object detection and analysis.
so far in our project we can subscribed to pointcloud.
but the question is how to stored it in pcd file or is there any better solution for that??
and how to use pcl for that ??

any help would be appreciated! thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11640/ros-pcl-question/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2011-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe [this](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html#gaab641ec94f63cfaf3ebd64a8a1f7969c) will help you write pcd files. Though if you want to do object detection, you're probably better of using the pointcloud data directly. Check out the [tutorials](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/) on pointclouds.org for more info.

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0